# Capturar flechas del teclado en Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, teclado

He estado realizando un proyecto escolaren c++ en el que me pidieron que creara el juego 2048, lo cree en linea de consola como base, y luego hice el diseño en gráfico, pero al quererlo implementar me he topado con el problema de que tildaba al momento de iniciar la aplicación, me puse a revisar, y resulta que en el ciclo en el que le pido un carácter al usuario "getch()" me esta regresando en ascii un "-1", (antes de instalar el filtro de eventos me regresaba un "-32") por lo que entra, se cicla, y de ahí no sale mas, con lo que me tilda la aplicación y no responde.

Me gustaría saber como capturar las flechas del teclado, ya que es lo mas sencillo, la otra idea que tenia era que en un bloque de texto capturara las letras, pero me parece algo molesto a la vista del usuario final.

Aqui les dejo el codigo de mi programa:

```
G2048::G2048(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::G2048){

    ui->setupUi(this);
    EventKeyGame* evento = new EventKeyGame;
    ui->pushButton_Start->installEventFilter(evento);

}

void G2048::on_pushButton_Start_clicked(){

    int casillaRandom = 0;
    char tecla;
    int tablero[4][4];
    limpiarTablero(tablero);

    cargarCasilla(tablero, &casillaRandom);
    cargarCasilla(tablero, &casillaRandom);

    arriba(tablero);
    imprimirTablero(tablero);


     do{
        tecla = getch();
        cout<<(int)tecla<<endl;
            switch(tecla){
                case 72:
                    arriba(tablero);
                    cargarCasilla(tablero, &casillaRandom);
                    imprimirTablero(tablero);
                    break;
                case 75:
                    izquierda(tablero);
                    cargarCasilla(tablero, &casillaRandom);
                    imprimirTablero(tablero);
                    break;
                case 77:
                    derecha(tablero);
                    cargarCasilla(tablero, &casillaRandom);
                    imprimirTablero(tablero);
                    break;
                case 80:
                    abajo(tablero);
                    cargarCasilla(tablero, &casillaRandom);
                    imprimirTablero(tablero);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }while(true);

}
```

Y el filtro de evento que esta instalado en el boton es este:

```
bool EventKeyGame::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){

    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Left || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Right){
            qDebug("Valid Key");
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }

}
```

Lo de el filtro de eventos lo vi en estos enlaces:

[Capturas pulsaciones de teclados con QT y C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26056/capturas-pulsaciones-de-teclados-con-qt-y-c)

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Intente también capturar con Open GL, pero no puedo saber si mi maestra tendrá el header.

Otra idea que tenia era de hacer uso de botones gráficos, pero sigue siendo un poco molesto mover el ratón, ademas de que pasar la variable tablero a cada botón seria largo de programar.

Comment: El problema es que las teclas mandan mas de un valor al getch(). Prueba capturar dos veces para saber el valor de las flechas. Por ejemplo: int tecla;

 tecla = getch();
 cout << tecla<< endl;
 tecla = getch();
 cout << tecla << endl;

 getch();

Comment: @JYass no se debe usar getch() dentro de un GUI, Qt ofrece herramientas de más alto nivel para estas tareas, nunca las uses ni las recomiendes, Qt es una libreria muy madura que ya maneja estos eventos.

Comment: @eyllanesc el comentario va de acuerdo al código que el OP puso, y el problema en su código es que getch manda mas de un objeto al buffer.

Comment: @JYass Una de las cosas que SO indica en [answer] es que debes indicarle al autor si es correcto lo que esta haciendo, en SO buscamos respuestas de calidad, no tan solo respuestas. Si esta por una *mal camino* hay que conducirlo por el *camino del bien* :D

Comment: @eyllanesc claro, pero por lo visto el OP tampoco sabía que la pulsación de un tecla como la flecha manda más de un valor al buffer y por ello el primer getch no devolvía su código numérico. Creo que de esto también aprende algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya conocía el dato de que mandaba mas de un dato el getch(), pero esperaba a que se limpiara con el ciclo, dado que la opción default se encargaba de este, en la de consola me mandaba -27, muchas gracias por la aclaracion :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debes usar un bucle infinito o que tome mucho tiempo de una GUI, si lo estas haciendo tu diseño no es el óptimo, y te recomiendo rediseñar tu aplicación.

En una GUI las tareas se deben hacer cuando ocurre un evento, en tu caso cuando se presiona un boton determinado. Existen varias alternativas para poder atrapar esos eventos, una de las más sencillas es sobreescribir el evento `keyPressEvent` que tiene todo `QWidget` como muestro a continuación:

***.h**

```
class G2048 : public QMainWindow
{
[..]
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};
```

***.cpp**

```
void G2048::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        qDebug()<<"arriba";
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Down:
        qDebug()<<"abajo";
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Left:
        qDebug()<<"izquierda";
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Right:
        qDebug()<<"derecha";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto es lo que trataba de hacer, pero no sabia como, de principio tenia el código que aparece en el botón, dentro de la función que se cargaba al iniciar la ui, ahorita mismo lo pongo :D

Comment: @Dykeiichi Si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como correcta, si  no sabes hacerlo revisa el [tour]